# Storage Transfer Service transferJobs.patch API does not work for nested object

Tags: google-api, google-client

Problem you have encountered:

1. Following steps at link below for transferJobs.patch API
   https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs/patch
2. Patch API works as expected if want to update description. Sample Below
   Request:

```
    {
  "projectId": "<MY_PROJECT>",
  "transferJob": {
    "transferSpec": {
      "objectConditions": {
        "lastModifiedSince": "2022-01-24T18:30:00Z"
      }
    },
    "description": "updated description"
  },
  "updateTransferJobFieldMask": "description"
}
```

Response: Success  200

3. Patch API do not work if want to update nested object field. Sample Below

```
    {
  "projectId": "<MY_PROJECT>",
  "transferJob": {
    "transferSpec": {
      "objectConditions": {
        "lastModifiedSince": "2022-01-22T18:30:00Z"
      }
    },
    "description": "updated description"
  },
  "updateTransferJobFieldMask": "transferSpec.objectConditions.lastModifiedSince"
}
```

Response: 400

```
{"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid path in the field mask.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

Tried other combinations following documentation/sample code reference but none of them work. Tried options as

- transferSpec.objectConditions.lastModifiedSince
- transferJob.transferSpec.objectConditions.lastModifiedSince
- objectConditions.lastModifiedSince lastModifiedSince Snake case
- combination referring to FieldMaskUtil as transfer_spec.object_conditions.last_modified_since

What I expected to happen:

Patch API to work successfully for nested object as per documentation I.e.  "updateTransferJobFieldMask": "transferSpec.objectConditions.lastModifiedSince"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateTransferJobFieldMask` works on the top level object, in this case `transferSpec`.

Changing that line to `updateTransferJobFieldMask: transferSpec` should work.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storagetransfer/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Storagetransfer_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1UpdateTransferJobRequest.html#ab67dcb76e3f47f8c710eedf625b9e5ac):

> The field mask of the fields in transferJob that are to be updated in this request. Fields in transferJob that can be updated are: description, transfer_spec, notification_config, and status. To update the transfer_spec of the job, a complete transfer specification must be provided. An incomplete specification missing any required fields will be rejected with the error INVALID_ARGUMENT.

Comment: Thanks @Anup Talwalkar for pointer. Error message was confusing as If one provide "updateTransferJobFieldMask": "transferSpec" and within transferSpec provide details for objectConditions only, error response had "message": "Data source was not specified.". Providing child level detail in "updateTransferJobFieldMask": "transferSpec.objectConditions.lastModifiedSince" returned different error "message": "Invalid path in the field mask."  Response Error message and document having Example as "user.displayName,photo" added to confusion.  Added sample below that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Providing complete object having required child field worked. Sample example for future reference to other dev.

Below job transfer dat from Azure to GCP bucket and during patch updating last modified time. Both transfer_spec and transferSpec works as updateTransferJobFieldMask.

```
{
  "projectId": "<MY_PROJECT>",
  "updateTransferJobFieldMask": "transfer_spec",
  "transferJob": {
    "transferSpec": {
      "gcsDataSink": {
        "bucketName": "<BUCKET_NAME>"
      },
      "objectConditions": {
        "lastModifiedSince": "2021-12-30T18:30:00Z"
      },
      "transferOptions": {},
      "azureBlobStorageDataSource": {
        "storageAccount": "<ACCOUNT_NAME>",
        "container": "<CONTAINER>",
        "azureCredentials": {
          "sasToken": "<SAS TOKEN>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```